# Opening Foundation Accordion Panel with Link

Tags: javascript, anchor, accordion, zurb-foundation

Does anyone know of a way to open an accordion panel by using an external anchor link in Foundation 5?

I've tried using an anchor link and it just loads the page, without opening the panel.

I've also tried using the responses already on Stack Overflow and nothing seems to be working.

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the anchor link is clicked, the page loads, scroll to the panel and then open it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the opposite, close the panel with link. I used javascript:

```
$( "#close1" ).click(function() {
    $( "#panel1" ).removeClass( "active" )
});
```

I think that with addClass and removeClass you can do all